# Loop Through JSON List Of Urls With RobotFrameWork To Assert An Element Exists On Each Page

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I have a list of URLs in a JSON file laid out as such:

```
{
  "urls": 
     [
        "https://www.fakesite.org",
        "https://www.fakesite.org/home",
        "https://www.fakesite.org/whatever"
    ]
}
```

I want to loop over them in robotframework and assert that an element exists. I am able to get it to open the browser, go to the first link and check the element. Then the test ends and doesn't continue its loop onto the next url.

The Robotframework keyword is written as such

```
I assert the element exists on the page
    ${url_list}=    load json from file    ../Json/myjson.json
    ${url_values}=  get value from json  ${url_list}  $.urls[:]
    FOR    ${urls}    IN    ${url_values[0]}
           Assert Oplists Are Visible On Pages  ${urls}
    END
```

I have it set to url_values[0]. If I removed the [0] it tries to throw in the whole list and tell me "WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'url' must be a string." so I know it trying to pass in the entire list.

This goes on to the keyword mentioned:

```
Assert Oplists Are Visible On State Pages
   [Arguments]  ${urls}
   Go To  ${urls}
   page should contain element      ${primary_element}
```

I have already opened the browser in a previous step, hence why you don't see the typical

```
open browser  url  chrome
```

It all opens up fine, does what i needs to do. The only issue I have is that is stops after the first URL and doesn't go onto the next one.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can try to use @ decorator in the FOR statement (FOR    ${urls}    IN    @{url_values}). The decorator tells robot framework to work with the variable as a list. You can always use "Log" keyword to see if you have the variables declared correctly

Comment: @JiriJanous that was it. So easy in the end, but I wouldn't have figured it out. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@` to expand the list into individual arguments to FOR:

```
FOR    ${urls}    IN    @{url_values}
       Assert Oplists Are Visible On Pages  ${urls}
END
```

This is mentioned in the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [Simple for loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#simple-for-loop)